# Graph matching to criteria

Tags: graphing-functions

I came across this problem:

Find a formula for the function $f(x)$ such that:

1. $f(3) = 0$
2. $f(0) = 1$
3. Vertical Asymptotes at $x=-4$ and $4$
4. Horizontal Asymptote at $y=2$
5. $f(x)$ is even

I can get any 4 out of the 5 criteria, but I cannot get the last one. I suspect that the function is something like $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{x^2-16} + 1$.

Any tips or advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The function you found is very close you just need a root on $3$ and on $-3$ (cause f is even). You can use the even polynomial $x^2-9$ for that. This will do the trick for $-4<x<4$. Now when you get $|x|>4$ you can use a different formula for $x$. Try to find a function $g(x)$ such
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
g(-x),x<-4\\\\
\displaystyle \frac{x^2(x^2-9)}{x^2-16},-4<x<4\\\\
g(x), x>4
\end{cases}
$$ And $g(x)$ has to meet the requirment of having $y=2$ as a horizontal asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

You had a good start. Let's write $$f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$
You noticed that since it has asymptotes at $\pm4$ you might want to write $Q(x)=x^2-4^2$. But keep in mind that's not the only solution. I can write $Q(x)=(x^2-16)^2$ or something like $(x^2-16)(x^2+1)$, in case I want to make it higher order. Why would I want to make it higher order? Because the problem says you have roots at $0$ and $3$, and since the function is even, you have at $-3$ as well. So the numerator is at least 3rd degree polynomial. 4th degree is easier, to keep it even. So I can write $$P(x)=x^2(x^2-9)$$ and $$Q(x)=(x^2-16)^2$$
I want to have both the same degree, so I have horizontal asymptote at $y\ne 0$. To make it at $y=2$, you just multiply everything by $2$:
$$f(x)=\frac{2x^2(x^2-9)}{(x^2-16)^2}$$

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the writeup, it makes a lot of sense to me. I just realized that I made a mistake in writing out the question, f(0) = 1, not 0. Could I approach it in the same manner or would it be a different process entirely?

Comment: Yes, you can approach it in the same way. Just use $P(x)=(x^2+a)(x^2-9)$, so $$f(x)=\frac{2(x^2+a)(x^2-9)}{(x^2-16)^2}$$ You get the value of $a$ by plugging in $x=0$